# ASP.NET Web page validation - dual form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

for a while now, I've been using client and server side validation helpers (as seen below) to validate forms on my website. I have now, however, got a page where i have 2 forms on, and i'm not quite sure how (or if it's even possible at all) i can validate each form individually?

Here's what i do for a single form:

```
// Setup validation
Validation.Add("PropertyName",
    Validator.Required("Please provide a property name"),
    Validator.StringLength(40, 0, "Your property name must be a maximum of 40 characters")
);
Validation.Add("PropertyType",
    Validator.Required("Please select a property type"),
    Validator.Integer("Please use the options provided")
);

if (IsPost){
    if (Validation.IsValid()) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO Property_Info (PropertyName, PropertyTypeID) VALUES (@0, @1)";
        db.Execute(sql, Request["PropertyName"], Request["PropertyType"]);

        Response.Redirect("~/owner/listings/complete/" + rPropertyId);
    } else {
        ModelState.AddFormError("broken again!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have 2 forms? In ASP.NET WebForms, there is only one form.

Comment: I want to have 2 forms on the same page, which can both be submitted independently.

Comment: @MatthewatCriticalCognition This is an example of the ASP.NET Web Pages framework - not Web Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Validation helpers conditionally. For example, you might want to do this:

```
if(Request["Action"] == "Update"){
    Validation.RequireField("SomeField");
    if(Validation.IsValid()){
        // blah blah
    }
}
```

However, this approach removes client side validation (which may or may not be important to you).

Comment: Thank Mike. So do you not have a solution for both? I'd be happy with just client side, but to keep my site as user friendly as possible, I'd like to have client side too.

Comment: You can use the jQuery validation library conditionally as well. That way you can add client side validation based on which form was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion Mike has provided you with is a great example to work around with multiple forms.

But there is another method of doing this too. There are two methods in my mind to work with this problem.

#### Client side Validation

Mike said,

> However, this approach removes client side validation (which may or may not be important to you).

If it is not important then leave this method and move to the next method, however, if it is important for you, then you can try out jQuery or pure JavaScript to work with the client side validation. It is not as strong as ASP.NET provides you with the validation, but you can control both forms on the very same page and check for the data and so on.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
</form>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" />
    <input type="text" id="age2" name="age2" />
    <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" />
</form>
```

You can use jQuery to easily manipulate the DOM and check for the elements and their values, I will tell you about a single, one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var name = $('#name');
   if(name.length < 10) {
     alert('Name must be 10 letters long');
   }
   // more conditions for the name!
});
```

This was the jQuery validation, that you can use and it would run on the client's user agent (browser) and will control both the forms and you can check for the data that is provided by the users by some logical algorithm.

#### Using two pages

This method uses two pages, first page would be the page where your HTML form resides, second page is where the data is processed. You can use the very same html form that you're using and just include a single more hidden input to name the form and then use it as a condition. Like this,

```
<form method="post" action="~/secondPage.cshtml">
    <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="form1" />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="age" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="~/secondPage.cshtml">
    <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="form2" />
    <input type="text" name="name2" />
    <input type="text" name="age2" />
    <input type="text" name="email2" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

..now on the second page you can use this.

```
if(Request.Form["formName"] == "form1") {
    // first form
    // check validation for first form!
} else {
    // second form
    // check for second one..
}
```

..and continue the process.